# Downloading a .doc extension file saved in stream memory - returned from web service api (.asmx file) to angular service

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asmx, aspose

I have a web service (.asmx file extension), which creates a Document (Aspose.Words) which I save to MemoryStream.
I would like the user to download the file on click - without having to save the actual file anywhere but to the users computer when he downloads.
I am struggling with this for quite a while...
even if i manage to download the file - the content is not correct.

This is my angular code:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

Generate() {
    this.http.get(
      `${this.environment.Url}Generate`, {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      }
    ).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.downLoadFile(res, 'application/msword');
    }
    );
  }

  downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
    let blob = new Blob([data], { type: type});
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let pwa = window.open(url);
    if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed === 'undefined') {
      alert( 'Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.');
    }
  }
```

And this is what i did in the web service:

```
public async Task<Stream> Generate() {
    Document doc = _Generate(profileToCV);
    MemoryStream dstStream = new MemoryStream();                               
    doc.Save(dstStream, SaveFormat.Docx);
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(dstStream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "foo";
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = dstStream.GetBuffer().Length;
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

I tried alot of different variations.
like changing the responseType returned to 'blob' or 'blob' as 'json',
or returning the HttpResponseMessage.
nothing worked as expected.
I can't seem to extract the content saved in what is returned to client properly in file.

so - Help! ... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a link element and fire click event,

```
this.blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'}); // your file format

  var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = downloadURL;
  link.download = "help.pdf";
  link.click();
```